# Application of BET to micropore

Tags: catalysis, adsorption

'application of the BET equation should be restricted to the range where the term n(1 – p/p0) continuously increases with p/p0'[see 5.2.2 in the reference](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/pac.2015.87.issue-9-10/pac-2014-1117/pac-2014-1117.xml)
This is one of the criterias IUPAC proposes for BET to be applied to micropores. 
What is the physical meanning of n(1 – p/p0) and why does it need to increase?

Comment: OK, I was tracking a little the meaning of it. Rouquerol's adsorption book traces it to the paper DOI: 10.1016/S0167-2991(07)80008-5
From this paper, it goes to the Keii article in Anal. Chem. (https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ac50154a063) but in here I could not find it clearly. The other possible reference, is [6] J.B. Parra, J.C. de Sousa, R.C. Bansal, J.J. Pis and J.A. Pajares, Adsorption Sci. Tech., 11 (1994) 51. Which I don't have the book now to check... if I remember, I will look at it tomorrow back at the office.

Comment: I checked [the paper by Parra et al.](https://doi.org/10.1177/026361749501200106) and it also does not explain much. Just mentions using the alternative linear form by Keii which is more sensitive to deviations from linearity.

Comment: I checked Keii's paper. I think the increasing of n(1 – p/p0) means the forming of monolayer. When it stops increasing, the second layer starts to form.